# Scrapy: '//select/option' xpath not yielding any results

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been trying Scrapy and absolutely love it. However, one of the things I'm testing it in does not seem to work.

I'm trying to scrape a page (apple.com, for example) and save a list of the keyboard options available, using the simple xpath

```
//select/option
```

When using Chrome console, the website below comes back with an array of selections that I can easily iterate through, however, if I use scrapy.response.xpath('//select/option') via the scraper, or via the console, I get nothing back from it.

My code for the scraper looks a bit like the below (edited for simplicity)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html
from apple.items import AppleItem


class ApplekbSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'applekb'
    allowed_domains = ['apple.com']
    start_urls = ('http://www.apple.com/ae/shop/buy-mac/imac?product=MK482&step=config#', )

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//select/option'):
            item = AppleItem()
            item['country'] = sel.xpath('//span[@class="as-globalfooter-locale-name"]/text()').extract()
            item['kb'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            item['code'] = sel.xpath('@value').extract()
            yield item
```

As you can see I'm trying to get the code and text for each option, along with the site "Locale Name" (country).

As a side note, I've tried with CSS selectors to no avail. Anyone knows what I'm missing?

Thanks a lot in advance,
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the usage of JavaScript by the webpage. When you open the url in the Chrome, the JavaScript code is executed by the browser, which generates the drop-down-menu with the keyboard options.

You should check out a headless-browser ([PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) etc.) which will do the JavaScript execution. With [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), Scrapy offers its own headless-browser which can be easily integrated via `scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware` Downloader Middleware.

https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

Answer (score 0):

The cause that `//select/option` does not find anything is that there is no `select` tag in the website when you load it with scrapy. That's because JavaScript is not executed and the dropdown is not filled with values.

Try to disable javascript from your Chrome developer tools' settings and you should see the same empty website what scrapy sees when you scrape the page.

Comment: Aha! That's exactly what I see in Scrapy! Thanks for the hint. Now, is there any way for scrapy to get the right thing? Or should I switch to Selenium?